# Finding the height of a binary search tree

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I'm having trouble getting used to the recursion in Haskell, is there anyway someone could explain to me how I would go about this.
I've looked at a bunch of other posts, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have my type as

```
data BST = MakeNode BST String BST
             | Empty
```

I'm not sure how'd i'd examine every single combo of paths down the tree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick to thinking about most recursive functions is simple: first consider the base case, then consider the recursive case.

The base case is usually trivial--when do you know the height of a tree without any additional calculations? When it has no children, of course! So the base case is:

```
height Empty = 0
```

That was pretty straightforward. Now the next question: what is the height of a binary tree *with* children?

Well, that's also simple--it's 1, for the current node, plus the height of the tallest subtree. So:

```
height MakeNode left _ right = 1 + max (height left) (height right)
```

(The `_` just means we don't care about the string in the node.)

And so we have a very simple function:

```
height :: BST -> Int
height Empty              = 0
height (BST left _ right) = 1 + max (height left) (height right)
```

I hope this clarifies the thought process of designing a recursive function.

Comment: thanks alot for the response, and now I understand the logic, however I'm getting an error.


Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `BST'
    In the first argument of `length', namely `left'
    In the first argument of `max', namely `(length left)'
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely
      `max (length left) (length right)'

Comment: @user1204349 You may want to change `length` to `height`.

Comment: thanks, bereal. Obvious mistake, should have found it myself.

Comment: I'm still trying to make recursion second nature, and I'm still slow. How would I add a new node.  I understand the whole left/right deal, as I just made a search function. Anyone have any hints on this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: The base case should be Empty = 0. Consider a tree with only a root node this will give the calculation 1 + (depth of childnodes = 1) = 2

Comment: @nist: Yeah, you're right. I was thinking of `Empty` as a node with no children, but, in retrospect, that makes no sense at all.

Comment: @user1204349: If you have an unrelated question, you should post it separately rather than in the comments. You'll get better answers faster that way.

Answer (score 1):

Any tree of that type will have infinite height since there is no way to represent a leaf.

If the type were defined as:

```
data BST = MakeNode BST String BST
         | MakeLeaf
```

then the height of a leaf is 0, and the height of a node is 1 plus the maximum height of its two subtrees.

Comment: i forgot to add the Empty part

Comment: +1 for not giving actual code - as always, the problem with our adept is that he cannot even formulate in english what the height of a tree is (or at least he doesn't show us that he can), hence his difficulties with the ohh so complicated recursion. I wish more people here would take on the habit to say: "If and only if you can tell us in english, then we tell you in haskell."